# unable to call azure signalr hub method using azure signalr rest api

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have created a sample .net core app with azure signalr service and hosted at local iis.

i) I am using below url in postman to call hub method:
   http://azuresignalr:5002/api/v1-preview/hub/:NotificationHub

ii) calling with postman with below body:

{
    "Message":  {
                    "target": "BroadcastMessage",
                     "arguments": [
                        "test method"
                ]
                  }
}

iii) My c# class :

public class NotificationHub:Hub
    {

```
    public string TestConnection()
    {
        return "connected";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void BroadcastMessage([FromBody]object message)
    {
        message = "Modified Message from Azure Signal R server " + message;

        Clients.All.SendAsync("broadcastMessage", message);

    }
}
```

but I am getting 404 error in postman.

Any help or document regarding its implementation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do that, because no connection is established.** A hub is not the same like a controller which you can use for creating restendpoints.

Normally your client should create a connection to the server, after that you can communicate over this "channel".

Why do you do this?

(For details signalr information start with https://www.asp.net/signalr)